# React Bit Dev module is saying 404

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, bit.dev

I am trying to use following bit.dev community reusable component ( semantic-ui-react table ) in my application, link I am trying is as below:

https://bit.dev/semantic-org/semantic-ui-react/table?example=5c920bc8c634f0001a931879

We can use same in application using `npm i @bit/semantic-org.semantic-ui-react.table`

But whenever I do that following error ( Note : For other @bit modules also we are getting same issue ) :

```
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@bit%2fsemantic-org.semantic-ui-react.table - Not found
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404  '@bit/semantic-org.semantic-ui-react.table@latest' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.
```

Comment: is this bit.dev package hosted in npm ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you get this error because you have not configured `@bit` as a registry.
https://docs.bit.dev/docs/installing-components.html

Comment: Let me check this

Comment: Thank you, kind internet person, for saving me from tearing my hair out :)

Answer (score 1):

I also faced same problem for pulling a component from my private collection. In the official [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E5lgoz6-nfs&lc=UgxK6L53Vny5S1zvIDh4AaABAg&feature=em-comments) video registry configuration step is missing.

To install components with npm or yarn we first need to configure @bit as a [scoped registry](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/using-npm/scope). Bit does it by default as part of the bit login process.

To configure the registry manually, use the npm config command. (For pulling public components)

```
npm config set @bit:registry https://node.bit.dev
```

To install private components use npm login. Use your Bit credentials to login.

```
npm login --registry=https://node.bit.dev --scope=@bit
```

(This will prompt for user login via CLI.)